# How to transpose a matrix without using numpy or zip (or other imports)

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

How do you transpose a matrix without using numpy or zip or other imports?

I thought this was the answer but it does not work if the matrix has only 1 row...

`[[row[i] for row in data] for i in range(len(data[1]))]`

Comment: do you mean one row like `m=[1,2,3]` or `m=[[1,2,3]]` ?

Comment: `[1]` should be `[0]` .... `[[row[i] for row in data] for i in range(len(data[0]))]`

Comment: cmd you are totally right, thanks for catching that it was driving me nuts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[[row[i] for row in data] for i in range(len(data[0]))]`